# CoreData: findAll returns objects, but simple fetchRequest does return 0 objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am using CoreData and executing the following command returns a number of objects:

```
 [Contact findAll];
```

However when I setup a simple `NSFetchrequest` like so, I get 0 objects.

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
                                     initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                     managedObjectContext:self.context
                                     sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                     cacheName:nil];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *array = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here. Since I don't have a Predicate set, I would expect to get the same number of objects, but I get an array with 0 objects and `error = nil`.

Please note that `self.context` is not nil.

Comment: Do you get an empty array, or do you get nothing at all?

Comment: @Jim: I get an empty array. I updated my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Where is the `findAll` method defined?  I don't think it's a standard part of Core Data.

Comment: @JIM: This is correct. `findAll` is defined inside RestKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using RESTKit, I'm guessing that RESTKit is setting up its own Core Data context/store and when you're doing it manually, you're using the default ones provided by Apple's Xcode template.  Stop using `self.context` and get the context from RESTKit, or use one of RESTKit's convenience methods such as `objectsWithFetchRequest:`.

Comment: That seems to be exactly right, as soon as I switch context, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

RestKit as of 0.10 maintains a per-thread object store. This can be tricky if RestKit hasn't finished with your data (ie: your RKRequestQueue has finished but it's still processing your mappings).

You can access a foreign store with the Active Record categories, ie:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *restContext = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore] managedObjectContextForCurrentThread];
NSArray *allTexts = [TextEntity findAllInContext:restContext];
```

Hope this helps!